# How to find out if the web server (Apache) a PHP app is running on supports HTTPS?

Tags: php, apache, https

Please note, I want to find out if it is capable of accepting HTTPS requests, not whether it's currently using it.
Please also note, that scanning ports or making any other [a]synchronous  requests is not an option in my case because it needs to be very quick.

Is there a way to "ask" Apache about it eg: from the command line?

Edit: Thanks for all the ideas but they are for "manual" checking of the above mentioned fact by a human like you and me. That part I can figure out, believe me. I just thought it's obvious that these phrases "[a]synchronous requests" and "it needs to be very quick" imply SOFTWARE in form of a PHP APPLICATION.

Comment: it'd be a very unusual apache install if ssl wasn't supported.

Comment: I meant if it's configured to support HTTPS and actually accepts HTTPS requests.

Comment: They are not. It seems you have not read all the answers. Check mine an modify it accordingly.

Comment: It's a bit of a weird question IMO. If you have a server, just see if mod_ssl and openssl are installed like with `yum info *` or equivalent. What exactly needs to be quick?

Answer (score 3):

you can check this by `phpinfo();` and also you can cheek that the [mod_ssl](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html) is on or off

[image]

Comment: mod_ssl enabled does not guarantee the web-server is configured to support HTTPS

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work. It shows SSL=yes but actually the server is not accepting HTTPS connections. But thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to run this code your page: `<?php echo phpinfo();` and you will get all info about the version and settings

Comment: And what exactly to look at?

Comment: Look for the string `HTTPS` in the output

Comment: On your screen press `ctrl` + `F` and enter HTTP, and it will take you the screen

Comment: what exactly do you want to know? that apache supports https: conections?

Comment: search apache's core configuration file:  httpd.conf

Comment: A httpd.conf hack looks like an option. But is there any "legitimate" way?

Comment: create an ssl.html in your root and point it to your site `https://www.site.com` then if it wont support it, it will give a warning

Answer (score 1):

If this is a server you manage:

1. Check if mod_ssl is enabled in Apache
2. Check that you are listening on port 443 in Apache's ports.conf file
3. Setup an SSL host to listen on the IP:port settings from ports.conf
4. Check that you are not blocking port 443 with a firewall (there are many options for firewall here)

If you have configured Apache and have not closed the firewall, Apache should tell the OS to listen on port 443 and it will handle requests.

If this is a shared server or one not managed by yourself - ask your server support/admin

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to check for HTTPS protocol support, saving phpinfo() information into an array:

```
// NOTE: This section was extracted from the PHP Manual, example from **jon at sitewizard dot ca**
ob_start();
phpinfo();
$PHPInfo = array( 'phpinfo' => array() );
if ( preg_match_all( '#(?:<h2>(?:<a name=".*?">)?(.*?)(?:</a>)?</h2>)|(?:<tr(?: class=".*?")?><t[hd](?: class=".*?")?>(.*?)\s*</t[hd]>(?:<t[hd](?: class=".*?")?>(.*?)\s*</t[hd]>(?:<t[hd](?: class=".*?")?>(.*?)\s*</t[hd]>)?)?</tr>)#s',
                     ob_get_clean(), $Matches, PREG_SET_ORDER )
) {
  foreach ( $Matches as $Value ) {
    if ( strlen( $Value[ 1 ] ) ) {
      $PHPInfo[ $Value[ 1 ] ] = array();
    }
    elseif ( isset( $Value[ 3 ] ) ) {
      $PHPInfo[ end( array_keys( $PHPInfo ) ) ][ $Value[ 2 ] ] = isset( $Value[ 4 ] ) ? array( $Value[ 3 ],
                                                                                               $Value[ 4 ] ) : $Value[ 3 ];
    }
    else {
      $PHPInfo[ end( array_keys( $PHPInfo ) ) ][ ] = $Value[ 2 ];
    }
  }
}

// End of extracted section ----------------------

$HTTPS      = $PHPInfo[ 'curl' ][ 'Protocols' ];
$HTTPSFound = mb_strstr( $HTTPS, 'https', FALSE );

if ( $HTTPSFound ) {
  echo "HTTPS supported<br /><br />";
}
else {
  echo "HTTPS NOT supported<br /><br />";
}
```

**ADDITIONAL NOTE: THIS ANSWER DOES NOT REQUIRE A "MANUAL CHECKING". IT GETS THE INFORMATION THROUGH THE SCRIPT!**